# Assembly Mips Matrix Storing

Tags: assembly, matrix, mips, mips32

I have to do a magic square in assembly mips for a university assignment I have been stuck for more than six hours trying to figure out what is wrong with my code. Since I am working with a matrix, to get the position of an `matrix[i][j]` I need to use the following formula: `i * total columNumber + 1`. And do address this on the memory I need to multiply it with a word. The code is the following:

```
for: 
    beq $s3, $s4, ShowQuadrado # for (c = 0; c < n * n; c++)

    mul $t6, $zero, $t6   # assign matrix adress to 0
    mul $t7, $zero, $t7   # assign adress + array pointer to 0 
    mul $t8, $t8,   $zero # $t8 = 0

    mul $t6, $s2, $a0 # i * column number
    add $t6, $t6, $s1 # i * column number + j

    addi $t8, $t8, 4   # initialize 4 to t8
    mul  $t9, $t6, $t8 # multiply adress por 4
    add  $t7, $t9, $v0 # add dress to array pointer

    sw $s3, 0($t7) # store value on $t7

    divu $t4, $s3         # divide c by n
    mfhi $t1              # store the rest
    bne  $t1, $zero, else # if ( c % n != 0)
    addi $s2, $s2,1       # i = i+ 1
    addi $s3, $s3,1       # c++;
    j for
```

Obs:

- `$a0` = column number
- `$s1` = j

Output for `$t7`:

```
4 10 1c 28 34 40 4c 58 64
```

Expected:

```
0   4  8    c   10 ....
```

Obs 2: There is a continuation to this which assign a new value for `i` and `j` every time it is on the loop.
Is there anything I am forgetting to zero or something I should not be adding?

Comment: That's using so many registers it makes my head hurt :) It's also unclear what exactly you want to accomplish and where the output you show is coming from.

Comment: Do a magic square of even numbers: http://mathforum.org/alejandre/magic.square/adler/adler.whatsquare.html

Comment: The output is coming from the address on $t7

Comment: Why are you multiplying each of $t6,$7,$8 by zero?

Comment: That's an ingenious, if somewhat non-standard, way to zero them :)

Comment: To zero the register and don't add something I do not want.

Comment: You ought to post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's not particularly menaingful to sit and reason about an incomplete piece of code.